# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

**Problem:** Given $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) =0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}=0$.

Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} =0 $.

I observed that just proving that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists will finish the problem. But I am unable to do that.

Also, from the hypothesis we get that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that whenever $|x| < \delta $, we have

$\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} < \frac{\epsilon}{|x|}$ AND $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} < \epsilon$

Now adding the last two inequalities applying the triangle inequality, we get

$\frac{|f(2x)|}{|2x|} < 2\epsilon({1+\frac{1}{|x|}})$.

But i could not proceed.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: $f(x)\not\leq\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: @Element118, yes. I will delete that  part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply telescoping sums to the values at $x,x/2,x/4,x/8,x/16,…$.

And use that for $|x|<δ$ you get $|f(x)-f(x/2)|<ϵ·|x|$.

Comment: Ah! got it. But what is the motivation behind this idea.?

Comment: You need to get from $x$ to $0$ and the given identity provides argument doubling/halving. This invites to consider $f(x)-f(2^{-N}x)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f(2^{-k}x)-f(2^{-k-1}x)$